# Should I set spark.executor.pyspark.memory when running pyspark with YARN?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I am investigating various intermittent memory related issues with Pyspark jobs running under YARN.

In the spark documentation there is a property:-

`spark.executor.pyspark.memory`

- Is there any benefit in giving this a value?
- Would this improve the reliability of Pyspark scripts?

Comment: What does the documentation say about the property? Have you tried it for yourself to find out? Seems like something that's straightforward to test.

Comment: I've read the documentation. What I would like to know is what issues I am likely to face if this property is not set? How can I tell how much memory python is using? Will setting this improve reliability of Pyspark jobs?